# How to move Android folder to SD Card in LG P760 to install big games?

Tags: external-sd, internal-sd

I want to install [Wolfs Among Us](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.telltalegames.fables100&hl=en) on LG P760 which  requires 2.5GB of space. I don't have that much space to even download the game, but I do have 3GB of free space on SD card.

Game installs itself only in Android folder ( `Android\obb` ) which is located in internal memory card. Back on my old phone, HTC Desire S, Android folder was default set on SD Card so I had no problem installing heavy games as long as I had memory on SD card. But my LG P760 has Android folder in Internal storage, so I can't install the game.

If you folks find me a way to set Android folder on SD card, or just install game in SD card, I will be really thankful to you! Here are few things I've tried :

- About [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD), I haven't really tried it. I think it just moves folder after game is installed. I don't have enough storage on internal memory to even download the game, so I can't use that option. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it only moves folders, not changes default install directory.
- Unsuccessfully tried the steps mentioned [here](http://www.softwaredon.com/2012/04/install-android-app-direct-into-sd-card.html). I get stuck every time I try to search for my device using the command 'adb devices', and my phone doesn't show up even after I have enabled USB debugging.
- Rooting - I didn't do it yet, but if process requires rooting, I'll do it. I have never done that before, so I would thank you if you could show me which rooting program to install.

Comment: As for ADB, depending on your OS there might be either driver installs or configuration steps required. You can check with our [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for a starter on that. Apart from that, I'm afraid there's no way without rooting. I've heard of a way ([FolderMount](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.devasque.fmount) if I remember correctly) you could map a directory on your card to internal storage, but I've never tried that myself.

Comment: @Izzy I'll try it, thank you for replying. EDIT : What program did you use to root phone? I've never done that so I don't know and I don't trust those applications that I find from internet, I'd rather hear someone's advice than downloading all stuff from internet.

Comment: @Izzy I've tried the way using command prompt and ADB settings, I set my 'Set Install Location' to 2 (External). Also, I checked location by 'Get Install Location' it said to external, but still, applications install on Internal memory only... Can you help me pick a good app to root my phone?

Comment: Check with [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) if it's already listed with a solution. If not, check the methods listed below the devices. If that doesn't work, please open a new question, giving your device specs, and include methods you've tried (and failed) – or, if one worked out, even answer your question yourself with the solution, and link that back to the list :)

Answer (score 1):

- Root your phone using the following link and steps: [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)
- After you are done, you'll have special permission to edit your Android settings as super-user, so then download Folder Mount from Google Play
- After installing, enter FolderMount and find the option to change folder directory (I don't remember this part well, I am sorry)
- Install the game, enter Folder Mount, and change destination.
- Enjoy the game

P.S. I was setting up my phone while I was in hurry, so if some steps are inaccurate or missing, I am sorry.